# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable in Recommendation System

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, typeerror, recommendation-engine, streamlit

I am designing a recommender system to recommend movies and while writing its code, I am facing this issue. Can someone please help me in sorting this? I have tried a lot. I am using `streamlit` to write the code.

```py
movie_list = movies['title'].values
selected_movie_name = st.selectbox("Type or select a movie from the dropdown", movie_list)
```

Comment: Just answered the question. Tell me if is enough or you need more information about the concept.

Comment: Could you post the traceback log?

Answer (score 1):

Try `movie_list = list(movies['title'])` instead.

**EDIT:**
This is more a `pandas` concept than anything else.

To turn a column of dataframe into a list to be used as `options` in a `st.selectbox` you must know the concept behind `to_list()` of `pandas`.

You can use what I've written before

```
movie_list = list(movies['title'])
```

or

```
movie_list = movies['title'].to_list()
```

The result will be the same.